# How to get raw text from multiple nested tags in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime
import platform
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
from itertools import chain
sdCel = 'http://www.linguista.ch/sprachschule/san-diego-cel/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome() # run it with chrome browser appearing
browser.get(sdCel)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

sellingPoints = soup.find('div', {'class':'column column_620   column_content'})
points_ul = sellingPoints.find_next_siblings()
list = []

for item in points_ul:
    print item.findAll('li') # .get('li') does not work: AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'
    list.append(item)

for newItem in list:
    print newItem.findAll('li')
```

This is the result

```
[<li class="calculate"><a class="f16" href="nc/kostenlose-  beratung/sprachschule/San%2520Diego%2520Sprachschule%2520College%2520of%2  520English%2520Language/" title="College of English Language: kostenlose      Beratung"><img alt="" border="0" src="fileadmin/img/icon_consultation.png"/> Kostenlose Beratung</a></li>, <li class="calculate"><a class="f16" href="nc/sprachaufenthalt-preis-berechnen/sprachschule/san-diego-cel/" title="College of English Language: jetzt online buchen"><img alt="" border="0" src="fileadmin/img/icon_booking.png"/> Jetzt buchen</a></li>]
[]
[<li>Beste Lage im Stadtzentrum von San Diego</li>, <li>Sprachschule  mit famil\xe4rer Atmosph\xe4re</li>, <li>Von der Terrasse aus geniessen Sie einen tollen Blick \xfcber die Stadt</li>, <li>Kleine Klasen mit max. 10 Teilnehmern</li>, <li>Hervorragendes Preis- / Leistungsverh\xe4ltnis</li>]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[<li>Schlendern durchs Gaslamp Quarter der Old Town </li>, <li>Besuch des weltber\xfchmten San Diego Zoos </li>, <li>Relaxen und grillen am Strand  </li>, <li>Ausflug Disneyland oder zu den Universal Studios </li>, <li>Rollerbladen entlang der Strandpromenade </li>]
[]
[]
```

I tried to solve this nested list with creating a new list called `list` and getting the `li` tags from there. I also tried to call .get() but that does not work either.

How can i get the text of raw text some specific `li` tags while ignoring the empty objects?

Comment: Without the `website url` is kinda hard to test an approach and see if it works to help you. But in any case, you can use `if/else` or `try/except`, along with the methods `.contents` or `.text` after you find a valid `li`.

Comment: sorry, i added url now. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search, by using `lambdas` for li's which will have either children or text to avoid getting empty results.

Here's an example:

```
example = """<li></li><li class="calculate"><a class="f16" href="nc/kostenlose-beratung/sprachschule/San%2520Diego%2520Sprachschule%2520College%2520of%2520English%2520Language/" title="College of English Language: kostenloseBeratung"><img alt="" border="0" src="fileadmin/img/icon_consultation.png"/>Kostenlose Beratung</a></li>, <li class="calculate"><a class="f16"href="nc/sprachaufenthalt-preis-berechnen/sprachschule/san-diego-cel/"title="College of English Language: jetzt online buchen"><img alt=""border="0" src="fileadmin/img/icon_booking.png"/> Jetzt buchen</a></li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'lxml')

for li in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "li" and (len(tag.findChildren()) > 0 or len(tag.text) > 0)):
    print (li.get_text(strip=True))
```

Which will print:

> Kostenlose Beratung
>
> Jetzt buchen

Comment: Thanks this worked very well! Just for the sake of being complete, the points_ul needs to be converted to a new string `points_ulString = str(points_ul)`.